# Name for the action performed by this chef with a pan

Tags: word-request, phrase-request, image-identification

If you look at this picture, you may know it is done by a chef who is holding the handle of the wok, and lifting it over the cook top while cooking.

What word or phrase could be used to describe this action?

[image: flying wok]

Comment: "tossing" is as close as I can come up with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The word is ***toss***. It's [often](http://www.recordholders.org/en/records/pancake.html) [used](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/tossing+a+pancake) [with](http://www.shortlist.com/instant-improver/the-perfect-pancake-toss) [pancakes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pancake), but it's also common with [woks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wok#Characteristics).

The chef is tossing the food in the wok. *Tossing* can also describe the arm movement. I don't think there's a verb that would fit “the chef verbs the wok” — *shake* comes close, but it's not a perfect fit.

For pancakes, *flipping* can also be used, but that only applies to a flat object which is moved in such a way to exchange the top and the bottom, so it's unsuitable for something in a wok.